# Raspberry Pi Filesystem

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a problem which I can't find the answer to anywhere online - so I thought I would ask it here. Below is a code snippet of the directories in my Raspberry Pi. I have a 16GB SD Card installed in my Pi, and the total size of all those directories is only about 5GB. When I try and install anything it says "Out of Memory", and I have already cleared all log files, etc to try and free up space.

But the real question is, why does it say full when it has a 16GB card and I've only installed apache2 and php5 on it?

```
edward@raspberrypi:/ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3.6G  3.5G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        214M     0  214M   0% /dev
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           218M  4.6M  213M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   20M   41M  34% /boot
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1001
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to type in: raspi-config and after that a menu pops up, with the option to expand your file system.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've just ran a filesystem expansion and done a sudo reboot. Will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: Great! No problem.